# Align submenu with parent menu element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the positioning of a Submenu in the Y-axis. And I want to solve it with CSS - not with JS.

Here is a picture of the current state:

[image: I have marked with red how the Submenu element should be positioned.]

I have marked with red how the Submenu element should be positioned.

If you hover over the left parent element - the corresponding submenu opens. It works so far.

My issue is that I can't dynamically align the submenu with the parent menu element.

When I apply the "top: " CSS rule I can only pass static values like i.e. "48px" that are based on the entire div. But I need it dynamically for each parent menu element.

Thanks in advance.

HTML Code:

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.first-level-dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 14px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
}

.first-level-dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.first-level-dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .first-level-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.second-level-dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  //top: 48px;
}

nav div div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

nav div div a:hover > div {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu-items" aria-label="menu">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="menu-button">Services <i class="arrow-down"></i></button>
        <div class="first-level-dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Services <i class="arrow-right"></i></a>
          <a href="#">Services <i class="arrow-right"></i></a>
          <a href="#">Services <i class="arrow-right"></i>
          <div class="second-level-dropdown-content">
            <a href="#"> Test Service </a>
            <a href="#"> Test Service </a>
            <a href="#"> Test Service Test </a>
            <a href="#"> Test Service Test </a>
            <a href="#"> Test Service Test </a>
          </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#">Services <i class="arrow-right"></i></a>
          <a href="#">Services <i class="arrow-right"></i>
            <div class="second-level-dropdown-content">
              <a href="#"> Test Service </a>
              <a href="#"> Test Service </a>
              <a href="#"> Test Service Test </a>
              <a href="#"> Test Service Test </a>
              <a href="#"> Test Service Test </a>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#">Services <i class="arrow-right"></i></a>
          <a href="#">Help</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Your second-level-dropdown-content does not show at all for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said in the comments, you code doesn't work pass the first level, but it could.

If your `second-level-dropdown-content` is always linked to the previous `<a>` , you could simply apply `top: -40px;` to your `second-level-dropdown-content` to align it.

If your `second-level-dropdown-content` need to move dynamically to align to different `<a>` , then you have 2 solutions :

1. Use some **Javascript** to get and set the position
2. Use experimental **CSS** "anchor" property as presented here : https://youtu.be/B4Y9Ed4lLAI?si=0wJevHi3FF2Vv82C